# Enum serialization with resource string

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-core, enums

I am trying to figure out a way to have some enum values serialized using a localized resource string.

I am using the [EnumMember] attribute whenever I want to serialize the enum with a friendly description. (for example if there are spaces in the description as shown in my code sample below.)

This all works great - however now I have the requirement to localize the string description of a couple of the enum values.  For example, if the enum SupportState, represents a US State, as shown below it is serialized as "Support State".  All good.  But ideally I want the EnumMember value string to be localized using a resource string.  That way see my culture/locale is en_CA (English Canada), then the enum is still SupportState in the code but the serialized value will be "Support Province"
I want to keep the same enum name but want the value string to be localized.

I am not sure how to do this - is there a way to get that localized resource string into the EnumMember constructor?  The [EnumMember] attribute is sealed so I can't inherit from it...

Is there a better recommended way to achieve this?

````
public enum Settings {

[EnumMember(Value = "Support State")] // want a localized resource string - eg. Support Province
SupportState = 1,
[EnumMember(Value = "Support Zip")] // want a localized resource string - eg. Support Postal Code
SupportZip = 2,

}```
````

Comment: I think you implementing this at a wrong level. This layer should only be concerned with serializing and deserializing data, location is a totally different concern.